# Enumeration of stable graphs of genus $g$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-algebra

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected undirected finite graph, let us call $G$ stable if each vertex has degree at least $3$.

Is there a computer algorithm to efficiently enumerate (repetition allowed) all stable graphs of genus $g$ (we define $g:=|E|-|V|+1$) if

(1)We ask graphs have no loop edges and at most one edge between two vertices.

(2)The graphs may have loop edges or more than one edge between two vertices. (For $g<20$?)

(The graphs correspond to filling natural numbers with sum $|E|$ in the upper half of a size-$|V|$ matrix. Intuitively there are ${\frac{|V|^2-V}{2}+|E|-1\choose |E|}$ many choices, and there should be many redundancies. The problem is whether there is effective algorithm to reduce the redundancies?)

Comment: By genus I take it you mean smallest genus of a surface it can be drawn on? (Sometimes genus is also used for $\#E-\#V+\kappa$, i.e., dimension of $H_1$ of the graph.)

Comment: @SamHopkins We define it as $h^1(G,\mathbb{Z})$ or $|E|-|V|+1$, thanks for pointing out! (Let me add it)

Comment: Ah okay. It's good to specify since those two notions are both very common. (Incidentally it also seems like you're assuming the graph is *connected*.)

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, thanks! connectedness should be added

Comment: do you know this paper of Maggiolo and Pagani? https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4777

Comment: For any given number of vertices, there are only finitely many simple graphs, so of course it's a finite problem for a computer to go through them and throw out the ones failing the connectedness, degree and stability conditions. I think the question needs to be tightened to have a nontrivial answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there a algorithm to enumerate simple graphs？

Comment: Well, you just write down all the simple graphs with one vertex – there are only finitely many – then all the simple graphs with two vertices, then three, and so on. What's the problem?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thanks! For $n$ vertices, from adjacent matrix there are at most ${n^2-n/2 \choose g+n-1}$ simple graphs for given $g$, with $n\leq 2g-2$, if $g=20$ it is nearly ${800\choose 60}$ and seems a bit large to enumerate..or maybe there are just really this many graphs? (I am thinking about testing the Brill-Noether conjecture for divisors on finite graphs, which is known to be true for $g<13$, and maybe it saves some computing power if we can enumerate graphs more effectively?)

Comment: @DanPetersen Thanks for the reference！

Comment: If you want to enumerate graphs *efficiently*, then that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: For $g=20$, $n=38$, the stable graphs are all cubic (that is, regular of degree three), and there are $310467244165539782$ of them, https://oeis.org/A002851

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reference! Seems really a lot of such graphs… I’ll try to think more about possible reduction on the other side